# GridCheckBoxColumn with an string value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik

I need that an GridCheckBoxColumn contains a string value from my table SQL for this row (id).
OBS: I work with ASP.NET framework 4, Telerik, C# and SQL Server.

The scenario:

1. in table SQL, i have multiple rows (columns sub_folder_path(varchar),groupM(varchar),groupR(varchar) are most important!).
2. in my webapp (asp.net), a call this table and create an RadGrid(Telerik) with informations from SQL (the same column name).
3. I need create an column in webapp (asp.net) 2 GridCheckBox (GroupR and GroupM), and for each row, I can choose just GroupR or GroupM.
4. When I select an option for GridCheckBox (GroupR and GroupM), I need move to .CS Group name selected (varchar) for each row.

My code asp.net

```
<telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="securityGroupR" HeaderText="Access to Modify"
                                SortExpression="securityGroupR" UniqueName="securityGroupR" DataType="System.String">
                            </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
                            <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="securityGroupM" HeaderText="Access to Modify"
                                SortExpression="securityGroupM" UniqueName="securityGroupM" DataType="System.String">
                            </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
```

Error: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

How can I create GridCheckBox that passes for my .CS group name for each selected row?

Tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with below code snippet.

.ASPX

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"
    OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound">
    <MasterTableView>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" UniqueName="ID" HeaderText="ID">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Get selected Checbox" />
```

.ASPX.CS

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("flag", typeof(string));

    dt.Rows.Add(1, "true");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "true");
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "false");

    RadGrid1.DataSource = dt;

}

protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;

        DataRowView dr = item.DataItem as DataRowView; // Convert DataItem into Your Assigned Object

        (item.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox).Checked = GetBoolValueFromString(Convert.ToString(dr["flag"]));

    }
}


protected bool GetBoolValueFromString(string strFlag)
{
    bool flag = false;
    bool.TryParse(strFlag, out flag);
    return flag;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items)
    {
        if ((item.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox).Checked)
        {
            string strID = item["ID"].Text; // Get selected Checkbox's ID Field Value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why this CheckBox disable by default? What's propety to enable GridCheckBoxColumn? You've other solution more simila to my case? Values not boolean but string(varchar), data coming to DataSource (SQL, Stored Procedure), an foreach to verify how group is checked=true for each row... Tks!

Comment: I have updated the above code snippet. Please try with above code and let me know if any concern.